# texttospeak interface speak method is not working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am working on app in which when a new activity start, then it should speak some word but in speak method is always showing me null pointer exception but on googling, it shows me we can pass null value. my method is as follows:

```
private void speakout(String textToSpeak) {         
    HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap();        
    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
    String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));         
    tts.speak(textToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
11-21 12:14:18.985: I/System.out(307): ip : 10.184.211.143 11-21
12:14:19.035: D/AndroidRuntime(307): Shutting down VM 11-21
12:14:19.035: W/dalvikvm(307): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 11-21 12:14:19.045:
E/AndroidRuntime(307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-21 12:14:19.045:
E/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.audiobus/com.example.audiobus.AudioBusActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException 11-21 12:14:19.045:
E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-21 12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-21 12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 11-21
12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):    at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-21 12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-21
12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):    at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 11-21 12:14:19.045:
E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 11-21
12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-21
12:14:19.045: E/AndroidRuntime(307):    at
...
```

my first edit where i am calling speak out method and intent thing .....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_bus);
        textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipEditText);
        welcomeNote= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeTextView);
        text = welcomeNote.getText().toString();
        text.concat(" , Please wait we are retriving information");
        System.out.println(text);
        speakout(text);
        Bundle bunble=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bunble!=null){
               //Getting the value stored in the name "IP"
            String IP=bunble.getString("IP");
            System.out.println(IP);
                    //appending the value to the contents of textView.
             textView.append(" HI "+IP);
           }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//In Main Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("text-to-speak","Hello world!")
    Intent intent = new Intent(<source_activity_context>,<destination_activity_class>);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

//In Destination Activity

//onCreateMethod

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String textToSpeak = bundle.getString("text-to-speak");
Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TTS_VAL_DATA);
```

// Declare it globally

```
TextToSpeech tts;
```

//In onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "we can use TTS Engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {

                    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                        tts.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
                        tts.speak(textToSpeak,
                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                    }

                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "we can not use TTS Engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Hope this helps you. best regards...

Comment: ip address?, can you provide sample to me